# Chrome redownloading the same Excel file despite it being replaced on the server?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, caching

We uploaded an updated version of an Excel file to our client portal. Tested it on our test account and it downloads the most up-to-date file.

The client that needs to retrieve it is using Chrome and when they download it they say they keep getting the old file without the updates. They switched to IE and it downloaded the file fine.

Sounds like a caching issue with Chrome, but I did have the press CTRL + F5 and they said it didn't clear up the issue.

Anyone experienced this issue before? If it isn't user error, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually force the browser to get a new version of a file by putting a query string after it, something like ?v=2.0 should be enough.

Comment: Would that force the browser to get the most current version whether it is the the most current version is the first version, 2nd, 3rd... 25th?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it merely makes the file appear as if it's a different one. If you want to force the file not to be cached, you should either change caching rules in your webserver or maybe append a timestamp string after ?v= using Javascript or your backend language of choice.

Comment: adding timestamp on each download does not work. Like this + '?t=' + Date.now()